# MongoDB 4.2 aggregation query to apply filter at secondary level

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongo and doing a POC on being able to query a document for to get the locale-specific values only.
Briefly:  A topLevel object has subtypes, each of which has

- 0 or 1 descriptions for a given locale
- 0 or more alternate descriptions for a given locale
- a name and an id

I want to be able to get all subtypes of a topLevel object that have a description for a specified locale (that much I can do).  However, I only want to retrieve all of the `altDescriptions` for that locale, ignoring `altDescriptions` in other `locales`.

Ex topLevel object:

````
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "top level",
    "subtypes" : [ 
        {   "id" : 21,
            "name" : "child type 1",
            "description" : [ { "text" : "type 1 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" }, 
                              { "text" : "type 1 fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR" }, 
                              { "text" : "type 1 es_ES", "locale" : "es_ES" }],
            "altDescriptions" : [ { "name" : "type 1 alt 1 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" }, 
                                  { "name" : "type 1 alt 2 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" }, 
                                  { "name" : "type 1 alt 3 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" }, 
                                  { "name" : "type 1 alt 1 fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR" }]
        }, 
        {   "id" : 22,
            "name" : "child type 2",
            "description" : [ { "text" : "type 2 en_US", "locale" : "en_US"} ],
            "altDescriptions" : [ { "name" : "type 2 alt fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR" }]
        }, 
        {   "id" : 23,
            "name" : "child type 3",
            "description" : [ { "text" : "type 3 fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR"}],
            "altDescriptions" : [ { "name" : "type 3 alt en_US", "locale" : "en_US" }]
        }
    ]
}
```
My query:
```
db.topLevel.aggregate({$unwind: '$subtypes'}, {$unwind: '$subtypes.description'}, 
                      {$match: {'subtypes.description.locale' : 'en_US'}}, 
                      {$project: { type : '$subtypes'}}, {$sort: {'type.description.text' : 1}});
```
returns
```
{ "_id" : 1,
  "type" : { "id" : 21,
             "name" : "child type 1",
             "description" : { "text" : "type 1 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" },
             "altDescriptions" : [ { "name" : "type 1 alt 1 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" },
                                   { "name" : "type 1 alt 2 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" },
                                   { "name" : "type 1 alt 3 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" },
                                   { "name" : "type 1 alt 1 fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR" }]
           }
}
{ "_id" : 1,
  "type" : { "id" : 22,
             "name" : "child type 2",
             "description" : { "text" : "type 2 en_US", "locale" : "en_US" },
             "altDescriptions" : [{ "name" : "type 2 alt fr_FR", "locale" : "fr_FR" }]
           }
}
```

The query properly excludes 'child type 3' since it has no `en_US` description.  However, I'm not quite sure how to get it to exclude the `fr_FR` `altDescriptions `from the child type 1/2 results.  The results are otherwise what I want.

Can you please enlighten me?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to replace existing array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to apply your condition:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "type.altDescriptions": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$type.altDescriptions",
                cond: {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.locale", "$type.description.locale" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nb8s8jUITx_)